# Error When Compiler Optimizations are on

Tags: c, optimization, xilinx

Following is a code I wrote for debugging an arm bare-metal application.

```
#define OCM2_START  (0xffff0000)
#define AAC_QUE_SIZ  50
#define UINT_OFFSET      (sizeof(unsigned int))
#define INT_OFFSET   (sizeof(int            ))

print("here...... 1\r\n");

volatile long long *pktpts =((volatile long long *)    (OCM2_START + UINT_OFFSET * (AAC_QUE_SIZ + 3) + INT_OFFSET * 4));
volatile unsigned int* t1 = ((volatile unsigned int *) (OCM2_START + UINT_OFFSET * (AAC_QUE_SIZ + 3) + INT_OFFSET * 4));

*t1 = 10;
print("here ----\r\n");
*pktpts = pts;
print("here 555\r\n");
```

When I compile the code with optimization on and run, when assigning to "pktpts" pointer it throws an exception. But that does not happen when i compiled the code without optimizations.

What I do is store a certain long long value in that memory location and read it using another processor core.

Can anyone tell me why it is happening here? I am using Xilinx SDK 2014.2

Thank you.

Comment: You've not shown how `pts` is defined.  There's no guarantee that addresses from 0xFFFF0000 will be accessible, but presumably you have verified that on this particular system, it does work (it is a legitimate address that is mapped in your process).

Comment: it is "long long pts" and yes the address FFFF0000  does work. starting from that address, I have about 63KB of accessible memory. In that code, "t1" gets the correct value but fails when putting a value to "pktpts" when optimization are on.

Comment: I suggest adding the declaration of `pts` to your code sample.  Have you compared the assembler between the working (non-optimized) and non-working (optimized) code?  What changes?  Do you have different levels of optimization available?  Does it break at all levels of optimization, or only at some levels?  (Which is the compiler you're using?  Is it fully up to date?)  If you're not accidentally hitting some undefined behaviour (which means anything is OK), then you may have found a bug in your compiler that can be reported — you have something close to a minimal reproduction.

Comment: What happens when you run that line in the debugger and what kind of exception are you getting? Also try changing to `volatile long long* volatile pktpts` and see if that makes any difference. Meaning: prevent optimizations on the pointer variable itself.

Comment: Have you tried to look at the assembler? Could you post both?